# JSF Input Text Placeholder

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, xml-namespaces, placeholder

I am using JSF 2.2 and I am trying to put a placeholder on some input text.

```
<h:inputText value="#{loginBean.studentId}" id="username" a:placeHolder="Username"/>
```

I have placed the following in the head of my xhtml document and added the
pass through name space:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"htth://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
```

However, I receive the following warning and the placeholder does not render on my page:

> Can't find facelet tag library for uri http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough

Thanks for any help and advise.

Comment: How exactly are you so sure you're using JSF 2.2? Is the expected version logged in server log?

Comment: I have the JSF 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2.0) jar file in my libraries which is build with maven.

Comment: All your imports are from `java.sun.com` so you can try `http://java.sun.com/jsf/passthrough`.

Comment: Just tried the sun namespace and have the exact same error message.

Comment: 2.2.0 is quite ancient and bug ridden. Use the latest (2.2.12 as of now) and retry. You also need to make absolutely sure that the right version is logged in webapp startup log. @gein: passthrough is new since JSF 2.2, so there's no sun namespace for it.

Comment: Updated my JSF version to 2.2.12 and the same errors persist with the namespace tag. Do you have any more advise? Thanks.

Comment: Seems like right version is logged...."INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885) for context '/lectureNotesWeb'"

Comment: Then most likely runtime classpath is polluted with a different JSF impl version, e.g. pom.xml also includes Java EE API and/or you're deploying to server already providing a different JSF impl out the box.

Comment: I am using Tomcat 7 application server and have the following maven dependency   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.12</version>
  </dependency>.  Do I need to make this scope provided or do I need to remove this dependency all together? Thanks.

Comment: I have decided to use Primefaces (not just for this) and found that it has a handy p:watermark  tag. Thanks for your help anyway guys.

Comment: I can't reproduce the _warning_. Tried with Tomcat 7.0.75, and `<dependency><groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId><artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId><version>2.2.12</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId><artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId><version>2.2.12</version></dependency>`. The placeholder ever works and no warning is presented.